# How do you set a radiobutton as selected using code in gtk?

Tags: c++, gtk, radio-button

A radiobuttongroup was created and several radiomenuelems were created in that group.
Clicking them results in the expected effect, but how do you set a radiobutton using code?

I've searched google for the answer but I can only find other people asking the same question without an answer such as here: http://markmail.org/message/3cpuikfcyszyf3xy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Gtk::CheckMenuItem::set_active](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1CheckMenuItem.html#ab2b9dca0ea2dbbbf9ebf5c52025d7656) assuming you are asking about gtkmm, or [gtk_check_menu_item_set_active](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkCheckMenuItem.html#gtk-check-menu-item-set-active) from plain old GTK.